# In Android Detect morning,evening,night hours

Tags: java, android

I  try to detect when morning, evening, night hours in android. Because i want to Turn a light on when the sky is dark.If outside is sunny turn the light off.

I can define time range for evening or morning. For example 6 AM to 7 PM is bright. But this values different in every countries and every season and also every month . Is there any reciever  or something in android or Java for this.

Comment: how are you defining the time range in code?

Comment: you need define a rule before program can do it, or machine learning.

Comment: @sanoop I want to say like  a rule.In background, I define 6 To 7 is bright then turn the light off. the other hours i will turn on.

Comment: @JiangYD i can define a rule but i wan to learn  if android has an receiver or someting else for this.

Comment: you can check the Calender(AM_PM) @Zapateus  if its returns ) then its AM and else

Answer (score 2):

There are some algorithms and libs too for computing sunrise and sunset times (try search for it).
Eg. here is one: https://github.com/mikereedell/sunrisesunsetlib-java. It needs the location and the timezone, it can compute times of different events related to sun. If you have the sunrise and sunset times, you can check if the current time is in their range (whether the sun is up) or not.